# Rails model validation on create and update only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

If I want to have validation only on create, then I can do

```rb
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

But how do I say on create and update? I tried this but it didn't work:

```rb
validates_presence_of :password, :on => [ :create, :update ]
```

Do I have to define the validation two times?

Comment: Could be a patch in the making... except how is :create and :update different from the default :save?  (Wouldn't :save be both?)

Comment: yep, I just found out that :save is both, thx

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By default, the validations run for both create and update. So it should be just:

```
validates_presence_of :password
```

The :on key just allows you to choose one of them.

Comment: the new convention is actually to use: `validates :password, presence: true`

Answer (score 12):

Only write:

```
validates_presence_of :password
```

No need...

```
on => :create
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this when you need to disable the validation on some specific operations, such as delete.