# Add forming before saving and validation without encumbering "validate?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, callback

I have a `before_validation` callback that reformats one of the entries. I need it to run before validation, to be sure, that formatted output was parsed correctly. But as far as I understand each time I call `valid?` to check if data is ok, the entry will be reformatted. Can I do this another way, because on `valid?` I just want to check if all the fields are valid and not change something.

Answer (score 2):

this looks really similar to this one: [Rails model validation on create and update only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393698/rails-model-validation-on-create-and-update-only)

You can do

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
  reformat #method call, not a symbol
end
before_validation(:on => :update) do
  reformat #method call, not a symbol
end
```

but it still runs for me when I call `valid?`. Not sure why though, because that's not in the context of creating or updating, so I feel like Rails lies to us in this case.

If you could make it into a `before_save`, then it should work, since that runs after validation. You said you need to validate that it's still ok when you reformat, so maybe add a new method to validate the reformatting, and do

```
before_save :reformat, :validate_reformatting
```

or add the sanity check at the end of your method that you use to reformat.

Comment: This won't work :(. First of all `:on => [:create, :update]` gives an error: `unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
       ... (self.validation_context == :[:create, :update])`, and then I add `:on => :save` the callback method is not being called on `.save`

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't read the other topic I mentioned closely enough, and it actually said `:on => [:create, :update]` doesn't work, and `:on => :save` isn't working for me either. I'll update with the correct syntax to do it, but it's still running on `valid?` for me.